# python FTP.stornline hangs after last line

Tags: python, file, sockets, ftp

I want to dump data via FTP to a remote Server. Because dumps can get really big, My Idea was to write a FakeFile, which dumps rows on demand, and returns it one by one in readline.

This is my MySQLFakeFile:

```
class MySQLFakeFile(object):
    '''
    Simulates a read-only file, which dumps rows on demand.
    Use this, to pass it to the FTP protocol to make the dump more efficient, 
    without the need to dump it somewhere and copy it over the net afterwords 
    '''
    def __init__(self, cursor, delimeter, table_name, query):
        self.cursor = cursor
        self.delimeter = delimeter
        self.table_name = table_name
        #query is something like 'SELECT * FROM %s'
        self.cursor.execute(query, table_name)
        self._has_written_index = False
        self.rest = None
        #file attrs
        self.closed = False
        self.name = table_name + ".csv"
        self.encoding = "utf-8"
        self.mode = "r"


    def close(self):
        self.cursor.close()
        self.closed = True

    def flush(self):
        '''No-OP'''
        pass

    def read(self, size):
        pass

    def readline(self, size):
        if not self._has_written_index:
            logging.debug("not written index! write Index")
            ret = []
            for desc in self.cursor.description:
                ret.append(desc[0])
            self._has_written_index = True
        elif self.rest:
            s = self.rest
            self.rest = None
        else:
            ret = self.cursor.fetchone()

        if not ret:
            return ""

        if not self.rest:
            s = ""
            for col in ret:
                s += str(col) + self.delimeter

        if len(s) > size:
            s, self.rest = s[:size-1], s[size-1:]

        return s + "\n"

    def readlines(self, size):
        ret = []
        line = self.readline(size)
        while line:
            ret.append(line)
            line = self.readline(size)

    def write(self, string):
        raise Exception("cannot write to a MySQLFakeFile")

    def writelines(self, lines):
        raise Exception("cannot write to a MySQLFakeFile")
```

If I pass it to an FTP instance inside its `stornline` method, it writes everything until the last line, then an empty string is returned and it hangs inside this function,
(in line 545 `conn.unwrap()`)

If I look into ftplib [source](http://fossies.org/dox/Python-3.4.0/ftplib_8py_source.html#l00517), it should break because of line 535 `if not buf: break`. 
After hanging, I look on the remote server, to see, that the file is completely there.

What am I doing wrong, and what prevents `conn.unwrap` from returning?